# lower_case_table_names set to 2, Workbench still does not allow lowercase database name

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed `MySql Workbench 6.2` with `MySql version 5.6` on my Windows 7 64-bit.

I would like to use Capital letters in my database name and table names. So I need to set the variable `lower_case_table_names` to 2. When I look at my Options file's General tab, it looks like the following:
[image]
Clicking Apply opens a dialog that says "There Are No Changes".
Regardless, when I try to create a database with a Capital letter, I get the warning:

> The server is configured with lower_case_table_names=1 which only
>   allows lowercase characters in schema and table names.

I have a feeling the `my.ini` file on the server differs from the one mentioned in the Options File configuration. When I try to add this variable manually 
inside my `my.ini` file, I see the text below:

```
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.
```

This is how I have been stuck in creating my schema for a few days now.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the mysql service?

Comment: @arnoudhgz if my restarting you mean going to `Instance` section of Navigator toolbar and stopping it via "Startup / Shutdow" option. I have done that. I have also tried stopping and restarting the MySql service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Windows, table naming is case-insensitive. That is, your `Customer` table and your `customer` table will always be the same on Windows. That's a limitation of the NT File System.  This applies when your MySQL *server* is running on a Windows platform. It doesn't matter where your workbench client is running.

(You can use mixed-case table names for different tables on Linux, BSD, and the like, but it's considered very bad practice: only do that if you want to drive your colleagues crazy. So be careful.)

If you leave this `lower_case_table_names` setting alone, you can use mixed case in your table names without problems.

The `my.ini` file the server actually uses when it starts is usually found in the `data` directory.  The installation procedure can copy a preloaded version of that file, like `my_large.ini` on top of `my.ini` depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: "If you leave this lower_case_table_names setting alone, you can use mixed case in your table names without problems." I cannot add a table named `Campaign`. It will be changed to `campaign`. But I can use mixed cases in my column names.

Comment: Quote: "If you leave this lower_case_table_names setting alone, you can use mixed case in your table names without problems." Workbench is definitely not allowing me to create mixed case table or schema names. I don't understand why you are saying it would.

Answer (score 5):

You can't even start mysqld after changing the `lower_case_table_names` setting other to anything other than `1`, which is the default.

`0` => You should not set `lower_case_table_names` to `0` if you are running MySQL on a system where the data directory resides on a case-insensitive file system (such as on Windows or macOS). It is an unsupported combination that could result in a hang condition.

But let's try changing it to 2:

```
# Specifies the on how table names are stored in the metadata.
# If set to 0, will throw an error on case-insensitive operative systems
# If set to 1, table names are stored in lowercase on disk and comparisons are not case sensitive.
# If set to 2, table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase.
# This option also applies to database names and table aliases.
# NOTE: Modify this value after Server initialization won't take effect.
lower_case_table_names=2
```

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqld
>   --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini"

```
ERROR [MY-011087] [Server, Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('2') and data dictionary ('1').
ERROR [MY-010020] [Server, Data Dictionary initialization failed.
```

After initialization, it is not allowed to change this setting. 
So `lower_case_table_names` needs to be set together with `--initialize`.

It is prohibited to start the server with a `lower_case_table_names` setting that is different from the setting used when the server was initialized. The restriction is necessary because collations used by various data dictionary table fields are based on the setting defined when the server is initialized, and restarting the server with a different setting would introduce inconsistencies with respect to how identifiers are ordered and compared.

> mysqld --initialize --console --lower_case_table_names=2

Then you will get following error in workbench after initilizing the server again with `lower_case_table_names=2`:

```
A server configuration problem was detected. The server is in a system that does not properly support the selected lower_case_table_names option value. Some problems may occur.
```

show variables like `lower_case_table_names`;

```
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| lower_case_table_names | 2     |
```

So conclusion: on Windows leave the setting to 1 because 0 or 2 won't work or as they put it: some problems may occur.

I do however now have my database and table names showing up with Capital letters. 
Which doesnt really do much because comparison will always be :

```
 # If set to 1, table names are stored in lowercase on disk and comparisons are not case sensitive.
 # If set to 2, table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase.
```

Nicholas

Comment: Quote: "I do however now have my database and table names showing up with Capital letters." Could you explain how you did this? Because in the previous sentence it seems you are telling people to not use `lower_case_table_names=2`. So should we or should we not? This does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If your data files are on a drive different than the C: drive, you may actually have 2 "my.ini" files, one will be on the C: drive and when you edit the Options in Workbench, that is the file that gets changed while the "My.ini" your system is actually working from is left alone. 
Check C:\Program Data\MySQL\MySQL(server version), to see if there is an .ini file there. If so, you will probably find it has the changes at the bottom of the file that need to be written to the actual working .ini on the drive your data is really stored on.

Answer (score -1):

In workbench go to : management panel > Options File > General > System >

Check the "lower_case_table_names", put value 2.

Close Workbench.
Restart Service MYSQL56

See img here [How to enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGEpw.png)

Answer (score -1):

1. Edit this file at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
2. Add following lines:

[mysqld]

lower_case_table_names=1

3. Restart mysql `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`